# Areas vs Folders in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am not to relate to Areas in MVC, why cannot we have simple folders to indicate modules, is the web.config which needs to be there, the below is the reason why i am asking this

Views -unfortunately for views it’s not possible. All the views must be placed inside “~/Views/ControllerName” or “~/Views/Shared” folder.

Answer (score 2):

The following article describes in detail the reasons for Areas and the difference between Areas and folder-based conventions in ASP.NET MVC.

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/article.php/c20227/Using-Areas-in-ASPNET-MVC-Application.htm

The essential idea is contained in the Introduction of the article:

> ASP.NET MVC relies on certain folder and class naming conventions to
>   organize models, views and controllers. A large application often
>   consists of functionally independent modules with the result that the
>   main application is essentially a bundle of these sub-applications. In
>   such cases, organizing various models, views and controllers can be
>   tedious. Luckily, ASP.NET MVC allows you to split your application
>   into what is known as Areas. Each area mimics the folder structure and
>   conventions as required by ASP.NET MVC. This article shows you how
>   Areas are used in an ASP.NET MVC application.

When someone is trying to develop a sub-module suitable for inclusion in any ASP.NET MVC application (as an example, think deployment/inclusion of 3rd party code via a NUGET package) then the Areas construct is very helpful, and arguably a necessity.

Answer (score 0):

Areas are folder structure which contains its independent set of Controller, 
View, Model. Consider we are creating an area called Admin then the folder structure for the Admin area will be,

[image: AreaStructure]

The same setup can be created by adding folders, Subfolder, and Required files.